# Как перевести код с Java на Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Подскажите пожалуйста,был раньше в Java проекте такой код

```
private static Queries q;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static DbHelper dbHelper;

public static Queries getQueriesInstance(Context context) {
    if(q == null) {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        q = new Queries(db, dbHelper);
    }
    return q;
}
```

Вызывал его в **public class App extends Application**
Как я могу его переделать под такой же аналог Котлина **class SampleApplication: Application()** ,и смогу ли вызывать как прежде в Java классах таким методом?

```
  q = App.getQueriesInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Test {
    companion object {
        private var q: Queries? = null
        private val db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
        private var dbHelper: DbHelper? = null
        fun getQueriesInstance(context: Context?): Queries? {
            if (q == null) {
                dbHelper = DbHelper(context)
                q = Queries(db, dbHelper)
            }
            return q
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо больше,а как это вызвать из Java кода не подскажите?Ибо
`Queries q = SampleApplication.Test.getQueriesInstance(getApplicationContext());` выдает ошибку `Cannot resolve method` на `getQueriesInstance`

Comment: Вам нужно либо добавить аннотацию @JvmStatic к нужному вам методу либо вызывать его Test.INSTANCE. getQueriesInstance()

Comment: Ну и если у вас всего один метод и он статический то вам незачем создавать обычный класс, для этого в котлине есть object

Comment: @Sergei Buvaka, Я честно говоря котлин начал смотреть только вчера,по этому в нем пока шарю совсем туго) Мне нужно как у меня раньше было в App объявить работу с моей БД(но теперь App на котлине),и чтобы я потом в любом месте мог одной строкой ее дергать)

Comment: Ну если это ваш App класс, то object вам не нужен. Просто companion object в котором есть ваша функция, как вам пример показали

Answer (score 1):

В Android Studio есть встроенный конвертор кода из Java в Kotlin.

Чтоб сделать это вам стоит нажать на файле который вы хотите конвертировать в Kotlin правой кнопкой мыши - и нажать *"Convert Java File to Kotlin File"*

В большинстве случае он работает отлично, но порой все же стоит пройтись по коду и проверить нюансы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он вроде не конвертит статик методы и поля.

Comment: Я сделал на своем коде так,в итоге то что он выдал,похоже было совсем не живое

Comment: Ну я только что взял ваш код и закинул его в конвертер и все ок. Единственное, что раз у вас только один метод и он статический компилятор сдела из него не просто class а object, что логично в целом

Comment: Если добавить туда хотя бы 1 метод не статический то он конвертирует в обычный класс с companion object

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо!
Решил таким образом:

```
companion object {
    var q: Queries? = null
    val db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
    var dbHelper: DbHelper? = null

    fun  getQueriesInstance(context: Context?): Queries? {
        if (q == null) {
            dbHelper = DbHelper(context)
            q = Queries(db, dbHelper)
        }
        return q
    }
}
```

И вызов через:

```
  Queries q = SampleApplication.Companion.getQueriesInstance(this);
```